# How to include external files into html with javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several files (header.html, nav.html, footer.html). I was wondering if there's a way to include these files into index.html while the page loads (or before) using plain js or jquery library. I know it's better to do it from server-side, but right now I'm working on front-end and don't have access to server-side scripts.

When I try to use $.load('header.html'), it gives me the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'load'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load()` function has to be called on a matched element.

```
$('#myDiv').load('test.html');
```

In this example, the content will be loaded to the `myDiv` element.

Comment: yeah I just figured that out! THanks!